# Set up array according to given excel sheet

Tags: python, arrays, excel, pandas

I'm currently trying to create code to calculate gas values using a norm. In the norm there are arrays given as a table. First column indexes the array position: "a(0,0)" and the next column the given value for the first array. I'm now trying to automatically fill in 17 arrays with their values. So second column second array... Is there a way to recognize the array position given in the first column and automatically creating an array for every new column? Sadly the given indexes aren't "sorted" because only some values are filled in.

I already tried sorting the values so that the indexes are ascending but as I said, there are "holes" in the array and i don't want to do everything by hand. The table is saved as a panda Dataframe.

```
Arrayposition   A1        A2
a(0,0)          43.63     10.25
a(3,1)          2.20E-06  1.25E-06
```

Results i wish for:

```
aA1[0][0] = 43.62
aA1[3][1] = 2.20..
aA2[0][0] = 10.25
...
```

Thank you for your input.

Comment: are the `Arrayposition` string valued?

Comment: dataframe.dtypes returns for that column: ```dtype: object```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you want as your final data. But you can play with `concat`, `pivot`, etc a bit like this:

```
new_df = (pd.concat((df,
           df.Arrayposition
               .str.extract('(?P<name>\w+)\((?P<x>\d+),(?P<y>\d+)\)')),
          axis=1
         )
  .melt(id_vars=['name','x','y'],
        value_vars=['A1','A2'])
  .assign(mat=lambda x: x['name']+x['variable'])
  .pivot_table(index=['mat','x'],
               columns='y',
               values='value')
)
```

Output:

```
y          0         1
mat x                 
aA1 0  43.63       NaN
    3    NaN  0.000002
aA2 0  10.25       NaN
    3    NaN  0.000001
```

Comment: As my final data i want 17 seperate arrays named: aA1, aA2, aA3, ... Those 17 arrays have to be filled with the values in the 17 columns. I'm not familiar with the functions you mentioned, so I'll need some time to understand it, thank you

Comment: From the `new_df` you can get, e.g. `new_df.loc['aA1']` as the first array.

Comment: I don't know what kind of black sorcery this is but it works. Thank you very much